# error could not find the main class program will exit after netbeans

Tags: java, class, jar

When i compile and run my program in eclipse, it works.
When i run my .jar program on my personal computer (Windows 8  with java JDK 7), it works.
But when i'm trying to run .jar in others computers, it doesn't work.

So i tried to run with command line `java -jar myjar`
and i got this message which i can't understand

```
java -jar "Bureau\Application SNCF\SNCF.jar"

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone understand this message error?
Thanks for your help

Comment: make sure compiling level and jdk version and java version of pc which will run jar is match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is always caused by the conflict of different Java JDK at compile time and runtime, make sure you are using same JDK version to compile and run it.

Comment: I think I posted my question too early in fact. As you said on my computer i compile with jdk7 and on the others computers there is jdk5. But how can i run the program without updating jdk on others computers?

Comment: that is because you use only jdk5 feature

Comment: Copy the JRE7 into that system and set JRE HOME to JRE7 & run using JRE7/bin/Javac yourclass

Comment: use the -target option, use this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) to help you